# How do I disable select option fields when I select a previous option?

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

I have two select boxes, one will choose the amplifier and the second will choose the cabinet that matches it.

My problem is that I need to add a value of disabled="disabled" to the Cabinet options if 'Amplifier 2' is selected.

I have tried a few options such as:

```
$("#amp option.grey-out option:selected").change() { 
   $("option.disable").attr("select[disabled='disabled']");
});
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<select required="" autofocus="" id="amp" name="options" class="select-model">
    <option data-value="500">Amplifier 1</option>
    <option data-value="1000" class="grey-out">Amplifier 2</option>
</select>

<select required="" autofocus="" id="cab" name="options" class="select-model">
    <option data-value="100" class="disable">Cabinet 1</option>
    <option data-value="200" class="disable">Cabinet 2</option>
</select>
```

I have started a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/liamtarpey/A7dga/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need something like that:

```
$("#amp").on('change', function () { 
  $("#cab").prop('disabled', $(this).val() == "Amplifier 2")
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gvalmon/shgfk/

More details in question may help to find better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Like this...?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#amp').change(function () {
    var ampVal = $('#amp').val();
    if (ampVal == 'Amplifier 2') {
        $('#cab').attr('disabled', 'true');
    } else {
        $('#cab').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ASMITH/A7dga/12/)